# Pricing of the compound coupon bond with PDE

Tags: interest-rates, pricing, asset-pricing, hullwhite, compounding

I am now studying finance math using Steven E.Shereve's book.
Using Interest Rate models, We can the price for zero-coupon with maturity price $1$ under Hull-White interest rate model[page 274] and Cox-Ingersoll-Ross positive constants model[page 275].

**My question is that the formula for price of zero-coupon bond can be found in various literature, and I wonder why it is not covered in any book about a compound coupon bond pricing formula.** Please propose **the price of compound coupon in Hull-White interest rate model** or let me know the relevant references. Compound coupon is a bond that does not pay interest before maturity and pays interest and principal at maturity, which is used in many financial sites, such as housing bonds.

---

My attempt to find price of compound coupon is as follows.

**Statement**
Given probability space ($\Omega$, $F$, $\mathbb{P}$ ) and, under the Hull-White interest rate model for the short rate $r$, given by 
\begin{align*}
dr_{t}=\left(b(t)-a r_{t} \right) dt + \sigma_{r} dW_{t}^{r}
\end{align*}
 the no-arbitrage price at time $t$ of a compound bond expiring at time $T$ is as follows : 
$B(t,T,r) = \mathbb{E}^{*}(e^{\int_{t}^{T}{r_{s}ds}} \, \vert \, r_t = r)$
with the initial condition $B(T,T,r) = 1$. Then, $B(t,T,r)$ can be calculated as $B(t,T,r) = e^{-C(t,T)r-A(r,T)} $ where
\begin{align*}
C(t,T) &= \dfrac{1}{a} \left( {e^{a(t-T)-1}} \right) , \\
A(t,T) &= \dfrac{\sigma_{r}^{2}}{4 a^{3}} \left( - e^{-2a(T-t)} +4e^{-a(T-r)} +2a(T-t)-3 \right) + \int_{t}^{T}{\dfrac{b(s)}{a} \left( 1-e^{a(s-T)} \right) ds}.
\end{align*}

---

**Proof for Statement**
Under the Hull-White interest rate model given by
\begin{align*}
dr_{t}=\left(b(t)-a r_{t} \right) dt + \sigma_{r} dW_{t}^{r}
\end{align*}
the no-arbitrage price at time $t$ of a compound coupon bond with an expiry time $T$ is follows :
\begin{align*}
& B(t,T,r) = \mathbb{E}^{*}(e^{\int_{t}^{T}{r_{s}ds}} \, \vert \, r_t = r) \\
\end{align*}
Then, by using Feynmann-Kac formula, the solution of $B(t,T,r)$ satisfies the following partial differential equation:
\begin{align*}
& \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial t} + \left(   {b(t)-a r_t }   \right)   \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial r} + \dfrac{1}{2} \sigma_{r}^{2} \dfrac{\partial^{2}B}{\partial r^{2}} + r \, B = 0 \\
& B(T,T,r) = 1
\end{align*}
and assuming the solution in the form of $B(t,T,r) = e^{-C(t,T)r-A(r,T)} $, We get two ordinary differential equations
\begin{align*}
& - \dfrac{d C(t,T)}{d t} + a C(t,T)+1 =0 \\
& - \dfrac{d A(t,T)}{d t}-b(t)C(t,T)+\dfrac{1}{2} \sigma_{r}^{2}{ \lbrace C(t,T) \rbrace } ^{2} = 0
\end{align*}
$C(t,T)$ and $A(t,T)$ satisfying the above equation are as given in statement.

---

How about my try ? Thank you for reading it.

Comment: “_Compound coupon is a bond that does not pay interest before maturity and pays interest and principal at maturity_” that’s actually a zero-coupon bond.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Then isn't the result of my calculation a price of compound coupon?